# Keeping a reference to the object itself inside member functions

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, this

Is it useful, in terms of saving time and reducing number of operations, to create a reference to `(*this)` in the beginning of a member function where using of `this->` is recurrent? Is it something that compilers (gcc interests me the most) already optimize for me? Are there reasons not to do this?

Example:

```
void A::checkBytes( const byte * dataChunk, uint32_t chunkSize )
{
    A & self = (*this);
    bool UTF8Valid = self.InvalidSequences & 1;
    byte current, expectedUTF8Bytes = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++)
    {
        current = dataChunk[i];

        // many tests with 'current' and 'this->InvalidSequences'

        self.Count[current]++;
        self.ChunkSize++;
    }
    if (!UTF8Valid) self.InvalidSequences |= 1;
}
```

I know every non-static member function takes its own hidden `this`. I know I'll have both the hidden `A * this` and the `A & self`. What I do not know is whether many `this->someMember` will cost more than many `referenceToThis.someMember` or not at all.

Comment: You don't need to do that at all. You can also omit the `this->`, it's implicit.

Comment: I know the compilers will understand I'm accessing members even without `this->` when no ambiguity exists, but it is just like if there was a hidden `this->`, nothing related to the `->` in `this->` having costs.

Comment: _"but it is just like if there was a hidden `this->`"_ It's indeed an implicit parameter given to non static class member functions.

Comment: @PedroVernetti there is an already implicit cost of `this` (since it's passed as a hidden parameter). How would making a copy of it (`self`) improve the situation?

Comment: As far as I know, the cost of `->` is not the same as that of `.` (I tested it in some different cases)

Comment: `value.member` isn't the same as `reference.member`, which exactly did you test?

Comment: @FireLancer didn't knew. I actually tested with values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. worst case it would consume extra stack space and need some extra instructions, best case it gets optimized back to `this->`.

`this` will almost certainly live in a register where possible, and a reference like `A&` is basically a pointer at the implementation level.

There probably isn't even a gain in trying to store a direct pointer/reference to `this->Count` etc., as on most platforms `this->Count[n]` can be a single instruction (e.g. on x86 I believe `LEA` will be used, you might check the disassembly).

Comment: The most obvious gain of any sort of aliasing is cutting long names short in order to increase readability. 'this' is the shortest expression in practice, hence no practical gain in a 'self' reference. But some readability can be gained through aliasing long-named members.